# Align to top of cell in DT datatable

Tags: r, dt

I have a data.frame with some fairly long values, enough so that they wrap over when rendered using `datatable()`. This causes the cell/row height to accommodate the long variables. The remaining values in the other columns are then displayed in the vertical center of the `datatable` rows. I would like everything to be aligned to the top and left of the cell.

Reproducible example plus two failed attempts:

```
library(DT)

sample <- data.frame(A=c("the",'First'), B=c("Second","column"),C=c(540,220), D=c("Another value",'here'), D=c("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean scelerisque tellus sed ultricies cursus. Proin nunc arcu, ullamcorper nec orci et, feugiat condimentum massa. Donec placerat mauris vel fermentum mattis. Nullam finibus est ligula, varius interdum nisl volutpat malesuada. Morbi ligula sem, eleifend in ultrices et, semper vitae ex. Morbi.","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean scelerisque tellus sed ultricies cursus. Proin nunc arcu, ullamcorper nec orci et, feugiat condimentum massa. Donec placerat mauris vel fermentum mattis. Nullam finibus est ligula, varius interdum nisl volutpat malesuada. Morbi ligula sem, eleifend in ultrices et, semper vitae ex. Morbi."))

datatable(sample) %>%
  formatStyle(c(1:5), textAlign='top')


datatable(sample,
          options = list(dom='t',
               columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-bottom', targets = 0:4))))
```

I would also appreciate any directions to general resources on understanding the use of the `options` argument in `DT`. The documentation has examples but I haven't been able to find a complete list of what can be done/how to implement it with the R package. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
datatable(sample) %>%
    formatStyle(1:5, 'vertical-align'='top') %>% 
    formatStyle(1:5, 'text-align' = 'left')
```

Comment: That does it, thanks. Do you happen to know how to do this using the second DT formatting type, via `options`? I am doing this in Shiny and already have my options set there, can't figure how to use `formatStyle` there.

Comment: You can use what you wrote, assigning a custom className, then using CSS to style it. Have a look [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html)